# Android News Rss Feed

Tags: android, rss, rss-reader

In my app I want to put my news auto

so I have Rss  link for my News website

Can anyone tell me how I can do it

**I want a  Tutorial for Rss Reader** 
I am so thired

Thanks so mush .

Comment: Using bold while making request doesn't means you are going to get the code directly, I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, then post what have you tried so far etc.

Comment: ok why are you angry Iam new programmin so you should to help us

Comment: First, i am not angry; second, the fact that you are new to programming doesn't mean everybody should gather around to help you, not if you didn't show any effort. Again, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before making anymore comments, then edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below tutorials and example. That may give idea about RSS FEED READER

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html

https://github.com/nerdability/AndroidRssReader

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:
http://blog.nerdability.com/2013/03/tech-building-rss-reader-android-app.html

It comes with some nice things like a custom db to mark read articles, but you can easily disable that.
You may have to adjust some stuff to match your items and tags. I had to tweak quite a lot, but at the end of the day it worked (and it was the only tutorial code I found that really seems to work properly).

Comment: Then I can't help you. As I told you, you would need to put some effort into it. We may be able to help you more if you pick one tutorial, try to fit it to your app and then ask here if you encounter a specific error.